A concept for a simple NN as a transfer function for an hydraulic cylinder
For a RL project, my collagues and me need to create a virtual environment with an excavator, which needs to replicate a real existing excavator. The idea is to have a simulator, which simulate closely the real machine and collect trajectories of data for Off-line RL algorithms.
Now: even having the weigths of the real mechanical parts, their moments of inertia and so on, the simulated excavator does not act as the real excavator. The reason are vibrations and above all the dynamic movement of the hydraulic cylinder, which is not linear. Its movement can be simulated by taking dynamical movement equations (as a mechanical engineer would do), but then I thought, that probably it can be done using neural network.
So let's say I would like to have a very realistic movement of the beam seen in the following picture:

Since there is a real mechanical encoder attached to the excavator I can read the value of the angle ($\theta_{t}$) at any time.
So I my idea is basically to take the input from the joystick ($a_{t}$) and the state of the system ($\theta_{t}$), concatenate them and input them to a very simple neural network composed by 2 hidden layers with 256 neurons each.
The output of the model would be the next state of the system ($\theta_{prediction}$). The model is then trained by taking the real value coming from the encoder ($\theta_{target}$) and fed into the loss calculation:
$Loss = MSE(\theta_{prediction}, \theta_{target})$
at the end the neural network should map the joystick inputs in such a way that the beam in the virtual environment moves almost exactly the real excavator and without the need of putting on complex equation systems for simulating the movement dynamic.

Is it doable or do I oversee something important?
